# Change text of ActionBar when switching tabs

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I hava an ActionBar with tabs on it.

```
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Hide Actionbar Icon
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
   // Create Actionbar Tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create first Tab
    tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new BusinessActivity());
    // Create your own custom icon
//    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.business);
    tab.setText("Business");
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

The BusinessActivity class in my example is extends Fragment.

**How can i change the ActionBar title when switching tabs?**

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't call "new BusinessActivity()" . you should either create an anonymous class, or set it to the current instance.

Comment: Thanks, but if o set it to this, how will i set the tab to open new activity?

Comment: i meant that it should run in the current context. for example, if this code resides in an activity that is called "MainActivity" you should set the parameter to "MainActivity.this" . in any case, you should never create a new instance of an activity (or a service, or a broadcastReceiver , or ContentProviders or application). they are created automatically by the framework.

Comment: But again i ask, how can i start other activity when i press the tab. i mean not only changing the title of the actionbar, but starting a new activity

Comment: in the same block that you change the title, just call "startActivity(new Intent(...,...))" . it all depends on the code that you've published here. since i don't know what is the surroundings, i can't tell you exactly what to write. if this is a part of an external class, you should send the current activity as a parameter , or use the application context instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

when you switch your tabs call

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("Your new title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        ActionBar.Tab t1 = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this);
        ActionBar.Tab t2 = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this);
        ActionBar.Tab t3 = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this);

        getActionBar().addTab(t1);
        getActionBar().addTab(t2);
        getActionBar().addTab(t3);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]